# Form Footer Slow to Calculate

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form with a few sub-forms loaded in tabs. I noticed the forms were very slow to load and refresh.

I eventually narrowed it down to the foot footers. Each form had a footer that did some simple tasks (Count, Sum, Average) for < 4K records. Ideally I would like to keep the footer as it is handy for quick reference but not at the expense of delaying the form opening or refreshing by 10-20 seconds.

Is there anything I can do to speed up the operation?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the source queries for the form footers?  The speed will be greatly affected by what exactly you're doing, and could be especially bad if you're querying queries.  The underlying SQL code would be best.

Comment: This is a sample one:=Count([AssetName]) & " Items with " & Sum([Qty]) & " pieces" & " stock value worth "'

Comment: In the OnOpen action of the form, perhaps create the VBA count and assign your string to a control box on the form.  Not sure if that would make it quicker in your case?